# Writing Text File to Folder on Desktop

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm wondering how do you write a text file to a specific location on the desktop such as C:\Users\tommy\desktop\transaction\ using StreamWriter?

```
    private void CreateTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.CreateText (TID.ToString()+".txt");

        outputFile.WriteLine("Investor :" +" " + InvestorNameLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Initial Amount" + " " +AmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Date Invested" +" " +DateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Period Chosen" + " "+DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Rate Chosen" + " " + RateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Total Interest" + " " +InterestAmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Transaction Number :" + " " + TransactionIDLabel.Text);
        outputFile.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Transaction file for Transaction: " + TransactionIDLabel.Text + "Was Created", "Transaction File");


    }
```

Comment: Could you please finish your other questions before you start asking new ones? I know the people who helped you with the question you asked an hour ago probably aren't going to want to help again.

Answer (score 22):

If you know the path,

```
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\tommy\desktop\transaction\\result.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
       sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
       sw.WriteLine("Investor :" +" " + InvestorNameLabel.Text);
        sw.WriteLine("Initial Amount" + " " +AmountLabel.Text);
        sw.WriteLine("Date Invested" +" " +DateLabel.Text);
        sw.WriteLine("Period Chosen" + " "+DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
        sw.WriteLine("Rate Chosen" + " " + RateLabel.Text);
        sw.WriteLine("Total Interest" + " " +InterestAmountLabel.Text);
        sw.WriteLine("Transaction Number :" + " " + TransactionIDLabel.Text);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
```

else create a file inside the desktop folder and do the above

Use Environment.SpecialFolder to get the path to the desktop.

```
string strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                         Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

Comment: +1. Just so you know, the OP very likely won't accept nor upvote your answer...look at their asked questions on their profile.

Comment: Sure, just thought I'd warn you and not let you get nothing for posting a good answer. I had answered them less than an hour ago, and they basically got me to write the code they wanted and then left.

Comment: You forgot to either (1) Dispose of the FileStream or (2) Use a using statement for the FileStream.